# parenthesis surrounding an acronym printed in list of acronyms of the glossaries package

Tags: glossaries, acronyms

I encounter the following problem when using the glossaries package.
In order to explain this, please consider the following (minimal) example:

```
\documentclass{article} %or book etc
\usepackage[smallcaps,style={indexgroup}]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newacronym{label1}{abc}{A Test Entry}
\newacronym{label2}{def}{Another Test Entry}
\newacronym{label3}{ghi}{Final Test Entry}

\begin{document}
\glsaddall
\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

and compile this e.g. via:

```
pdflatex example.tex
makeglossaries example
pdflatex example.tex
```

This results in entries in the pdf file like:

> abc (abc) A Test Entry. 1
>   def (def) Another Test Entry. 1
>   ghi (ghi) Final Test Entry. 1

The problem I have is that (abc) (def) and (ghi) is printed, a double of the key surrounded by parenthesis. After consulting the manual I found no direct method to
supress this printing except the use of a single level style like listdotted but that style is unsuitable for my needs. Does anyone have an idea how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upgrade to version 4.02 and replace the `smallcaps` option with `\setacronymstyle{long-sc-short}`. (I've only just uploaded v4.02 to CTAN so it may take a few days to make it into the TeX distributions.)

```
\documentclass{article} %or book etc
\usepackage[style={indexgroup}]{glossaries}

\setacronymstyle{long-sc-short}

\makeglossaries

% If you're not using a font that supports bold smallcaps, switch to
% medium weight smallcaps:

\renewcommand{\acronymfont}[1]{\textsc{\mdseries #1}}

\newacronym{label1}{abc}{A Test Entry}
\newacronym{label2}{def}{Another Test Entry}
\newacronym{label3}{ghi}{Final Test Entry}

\begin{document}
\glsaddall
\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

Produces:

[image: Image of result]

Answer (score 5):

You can create a new glossary style, let's say `myindex`, based on the existing `indexgroup` and use it instead.

This is the definition of the new style:

```
\makeatletter
\newglossarystyle{myindex}{%
  \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
    {\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}%
     \setlength{\parskip}{0pt plus 0.3pt}%
     \let\item\@idxitem}%
    {\par}%
  \renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{}%
  \renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{%
    \item\textbf{\glsgetgrouptitle{##1}}\indexspace}%
  \renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{%
     \item\glsentryitem{##1}\textbf{\glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}}}%
     %\ifglshassymbol{##1}{\space(\glossentrysymbol{##1})}{}%
     \space \glossentrydesc{##1}\glspostdescription\space ##2%
  }%
  \renewcommand{\subglossentry}[3]{%
    \ifcase##1\relax
      % level 0
      \item
    \or
      % level 1
      \subitem
      \glssubentryitem{##2}%
    \else
      % all other levels
      \subsubitem
    \fi
    \textbf{\glstarget{##2}{\glossentryname{##2}}}%
    %\ifglshassymbol{##2}{\space(\glossentrysymbol{##2})}{}%
    \space\glossentrydesc{##2}\glspostdescription\space ##3%
  }%
  \renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{\ifglsnogroupskip\else\indexspace\fi}}
\makeatother
```

Then, instead of loading `glossaries` in this way

```
\usepackage[smallcaps,style={indexgroup}]{glossaries}
```

just use

```
\usepackage[smallcaps]{glossaries}
```

and later issue the command

```
\setglossarystyle{myindex}
```

Complete MWE (note that I've also loaded `fontenc` to have bold face + small caps)

```
\documentclass{article} %or book etc
\usepackage[smallcaps]{glossaries}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\makeatletter
\newglossarystyle{myindex}{%
  \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
    {\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}%
     \setlength{\parskip}{0pt plus 0.3pt}%
     \let\item\@idxitem}%
    {\par}%
  \renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{}%
  \renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{%
    \item\textbf{\glsgetgrouptitle{##1}}\indexspace}%
  \renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{%
     \item\glsentryitem{##1}\textbf{\glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}}}%
     %\ifglshassymbol{##1}{\space(\glossentrysymbol{##1})}{}%
     \space \glossentrydesc{##1}\glspostdescription\space ##2%
  }%
  \renewcommand{\subglossentry}[3]{%
    \ifcase##1\relax
      % level 0
      \item
    \or
      % level 1
      \subitem
      \glssubentryitem{##2}%
    \else
      % all other levels
      \subsubitem
    \fi
    \textbf{\glstarget{##2}{\glossentryname{##2}}}%
    %\ifglshassymbol{##2}{\space(\glossentrysymbol{##2})}{}%
    \space\glossentrydesc{##2}\glspostdescription\space ##3%
  }%
  \renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{\ifglsnogroupskip\else\indexspace\fi}}
\makeatother

\setglossarystyle{myindex}


\makeglossaries

\newacronym{label1}{abc}{A Test Entry}
\newacronym{label2}{def}{Another Test Entry}
\newacronym{label3}{ghi}{Final Test Entry}

\begin{document}
\glsaddall
\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to add:
\renewcommand*{\ifglshassymbol}[3]{}{}{}
to the preamble